# Set UseZip64WhenSaving property from PHP-COM

Tags: php, com, zip

I need to zip files greater than 4GB so after a search I have found it is possible to use Ionic.Zip library throught the PHP COM class.

The problem is by default Ionic.Zip doesn't write zip files larger than 4GB and I have to define a property. This is the error I get:

```
Caught exception: Source: Ionic.Zip
Description: Compressed or Uncompressed size, or offset exceeds the maximum value. Consider setting the UseZip64WhenSaving property on the ZipFile instance.

#0 C:\inetpub\wwwroot\...\resources_disk_usage.php(28): com->Save()
#1 {main}
```

From C# I have found this property can be set as follows:

```
Using zip As ZipFile = New ZipFilIe
zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.AsNecessary
```

But I can't get how to define it from PHP.

Anyone?

Using PHP ZipArchive extension worked fine for files smaller than 2GB, so if there is a trick to allow use zip64 within this extension I would prefer but I think this is a zip restriction.

Thanks for reading,
·_-

**The objective**
There is a remote folder up to the limit, I have to move the objects from that remote drive to another machine to liberate space. The files are high resolution videos about 5GB of size.

Comment: I have read zip64 is designed for that purpouse so I wanted to give it a try. A quick help on how to created split zip files from a set of files inside a directory?  I  will look for that anyways later. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: You can buy the Zip64 extension for ZipArchive for $129 for single user license.  And they have a 45 day free trial.

Comment: The aim to compress the folder is because I have to transfer it by ftp but I am getting issues transfering a big file too. Apprantly to have the zip won't do the trick becasue it will be a big file to transfer anyways ... I think I need to split the file into small files to transfer one by one. I look for the split option. Thanks.

Comment: FTP issues were due the missing pasive mode for the transfer, so i will take a try to that extensions to save transfer time. Anyways I am moving the objects without package and it takes a lot of time but it is working ...

Comment: You can only get about 5% compression on a mp4 file.

Comment: Don't worry in comprenssion but desired. The sources are not mp4 but mxf those are for video like a wav wrapper for audio. I ended to move the files without comprenssion. Done along the weekend. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

I see you added that you want to compress and move large video files.  I don't think you'll get much compression depending on the file format.

The way I would do it is copy the files to AWS S3 storage.

---

The PHP zip extension has had Zip64 since April 2013.

I don't have enough free disk space on my server to create 5GB files so I could not test.

This first image is from phpinfo()

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

[image]

https://pecl.php.net/package-changelog.php?package=zip

[image]

https://pecl.php.net/package/zip

[image]

Comment: When I read your detailed answer which I appreciate I saw it as -1. Don't know why since I think your answer is clear and relevant